# How do I stub out a current user's attributes in a view spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, stubbing

I have a view spec where I'm testing conditional output. How do I get the spec to return the user I've mocked out?

**View file**:

```
.content
 - if @current_user.is_welcome == true
  Welcome to the site
```

**View spec**:

```
before(:each) do 
  @user = mock_model(User)
  @user.stub!(:is_welcome).and_return(true)
  view.stub(:current_user).and_return(@user) 
end

it "show content" do 
  #assign(:current_user, stub_model(User, dismiss_intro: true))
  render
  rendered.should have_content("Welcome to the site")
end
```

Running the spec returns `undefined method is_welcome for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this which let me keep the `@current_user` variable in my view and made the spec pass:

```
before :each do
  @user = stub_model(User, is_welcome: true)
  assign(:current_user, @user)
end
```

Then to test the conditionality, just ran another spec in a context with a different before block:

```
before :each do
  @user = stub_model(User, is_welcome: false)
  assign(:current_user, @user)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have stubbed the method named `current_user`, not the instance variable `@current_user`.

```
view.stub(:current_user).and_return(@user)
```

That means, in the view, you should be using:

```haml
.content
 - if current_user.is_welcome == true
  Welcome to the site
```

Notice that it calls the method `current_user` instead of getting the `@current_user` instance variable.

If you need an instance variable, it is recommended that you have create a method `current_user`, which gets the instance variable and returns it.

Comment: My ApplicationController returns the instance variable `helper_method :current_user` which returns @current_user. I just don't think I'm understanding stubbing.

Comment: you have stubbed a method, but you are trying to access a variable. The variable is `nil` because it hasn't been initialized.

Comment: you shouldn't/can't. That's why I say  to change your view.